# camera drivers with autofocus

Tags: ros, camera-driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you know any driver for ros that support camera with autofocus please?
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12346/camera-drivers-with-autofocus/) by [banacer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1538/banacer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect most of them do (assuming support in the underlying device).

I know [camera1394](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera1394) does. That driver also supports changing focus via dynamic reconfiguration.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on 2011-12-26**:
Jack, the question should've actually been whether any of the ROS drivers for USB camera's supports autofocus. After evaluating them all (http://www.ros.org/wiki/Sensors#Cameras), it seems that none of them does and we will now implement it for the uvc_camera driver.  D.